# How can I read a stream of key=value pairs in bash if the values can be empty?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

So I have several properties files that contains keys and values in the following format:

```
Key1=value1
Key2=Value2
etc..
```

So when I run this command to get the keys:

```
ssh 172.16.1.1 "grep -v '^#' /src/PTB.properties" | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'
```

I get the following output

```
userField
User
srcIP
srcPort
dstIP
dstPort
date
time
```

And when I run the same command but with `{print $2}` at the end to get the values:

```
ssh 172.16.1.1 "grep -v '^#' /src/PTB.properties" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

I get the following output:

```
User-Name
Full-Name
Source-IP-Address
Source-UDP-Port

Target-UDP-Port
Date
Time
```

So what I want to say is that some keys don't have a value.

That being said, I am running the following command to get those keys and values:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    USER_PARAMETERS_KEYS+=( "$line" )
done < <( ssh $ip "grep -v '^#' ${PARAMETER_PATH[$i]}" | awk -F "=" '{print $1}' )

while IFS= read -r line; do
    USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES+=( "$line" )
done < <( ssh $ip "grep -v '^#' ${PARAMETER_PATH[$i]}" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}' )
```

My problem is that `USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES` is not saving the null values. For example after running this command, there are only 7 items in `USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES` instead of 8 because the Key `dstIP` is empty.

Any idea how can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: How are you determining there are only 7 values in `USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES`?

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES`?

Comment: Bash strings, including strings that are array members, are C strings; they're *terminated* by NULs, so they can't possibly store a NUL literal (other than the implicit, always-there terminating one) in a C string, or thus a bash string either. That said, you can of course always assign an *empty string* as a value.

Comment: (and as far as I can tell, it's *empty* values, not *null* values, that you really want to store; completely different problem than what the title suggests).

Comment: OK you are absolutely right, when I declare -p array I get `declare -a USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES='([0]="User-Name" [1]="Full-Name" [2]="Source-IP-Address" [3]="Source-UDP-Port" [4]="" [5]="Target-UDP-Port" [6]="Date" [7]="Time")'` but I still can't echo that empty field or use it:
So when I run this:
```
for i in ${USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES[@]}; do
        if [ -z $i ]; then
                echo "empty"
        else echo $i
        fi
done
```
I am still getting all the fields except the empty one

Comment: I think my problem is that I am doing `for i in ${USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES[@]}` instead of `for i in "${USER_PARAMETERS_VALUES[@]}"`. Not I got it correctly

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it make more sense to capture the whole line and parse it locally?

```
while IFS== read -r key value; do
     keys+=("$key")
     values+=("$value")
done < <(ssh 172.16.1.1 "grep -v '^#' /src/PTB.properties")
```

This also avoids the race condition you get where the remote file could change between the first and the second time you read it.

Having said that, a minimal change would be to have Awk print quotes around any empty value.

Comment: Also note how we avoid using uppercase #or private variables.

Comment: So I tested it and it is working fine BUT it seems I am doing something wrong because now I am getting the `keys` and `values` arrays totally empty, but when I echo `key` and `value` inside the loop I am getting the correct output, so for some reasons `keys+=("$key")` is not working. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Switch to a process substitution like in your original code. Sorry about that. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: ok, no problem, so how can I have awk print quotes around empty values? Thanks for the help

Comment: `print ($2 || "\047\047")` though this will also replace a number zero with an empty string.

Comment: For some reasons, it is adding only `1`s to the array

Comment: @Steve the `"`s inside the awk script are terminating the `"`s you're trying to use as delimiters for the `ssh` command. Escape them - `\"`.

Comment: @tripleee ITYM `print ($2=="" ? "\047\047" : $2)` and of course since we're now using awk you should lose the grep, escape the double quotes and make it `ssh ... "awk -F'=' '!/^#/{print ($2==\"\" ? \"\047\047\" : $2)}'"`. You might also have to escape the ```\```s, idk. Try it.